# How can I override my navigation bar background colour to be the same as jumbotron BG colour?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I override my navigation bar background colour to be the same as jumbotron default grey type background colour?

[**Snippet**](https://jsfiddle.net/e92rspgj/2/)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Me</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Currency Currency</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.navbar-custom {
    background: #eee;
}
```